# If a shidduch says "no" to you, does that mean that they are not your zivug?

Tags: marriage, shidduchim-dating, free-will-bechira, bas-kol, zivug

If a shidduch says "no" to you, does that mean that they are not your zivug (predetermined soulmate)?

[Some sources](http://taliashewrote.com/zivug-vs-beshert/):

> Forty days before the formation of an embryo, a Heavenly voice
>   proclaims: The daughter of this one is destined to marry this one.
>   Sanhedrin 22a  When Hashem first created man, He created Adam and
>   Chavah together as one, and then He separated them. The RASHBA
>   (TESHUVOS HA’RASHBA 1:60) explains that Hashem first created man and
>   woman together and then separated them, so that they would later be
>   able to come together and be joined and feel like a single unit.
>   Perhaps it is for this reason that before the man is born a Bas Kol
>   (Divine Voice) announces who his Zivug (partner) will be — this shows
>   that they both come from the same spiritual root, and that the woman
>   that he eventually marries will be part of his own Neshamah (soul). It
>   would be impossible to bond their souls together in such a way after
>   they are created, and therefore Hashem bonds them together before they
>   are created in order for them to be able to bond together strongly.
>   (If one of them is a Tzadik and the other is a Rasha, then one can
>   influence the other to improve since they are bonded together so
>   strongly.)  –Talmud, Sota 2 (adapted from  Kollel Iyun Hadaf of Har
>   Nof)

Comment: In my understanding your bashert is who you marry, so if you later get married it is your bashert

Comment: This question is a little vague. On the surface it seems pretty cut and dry, but there are so many inherently connected questions that I think there must be one (or more) of them that ought to be embedded here.  Are you asking a metaphysical question about the nature of Bashert? Are you asking if people can control their own destinies? Are you asking if you can reject your Bashert and still be happy? Are you asking if you can marry someone who's *not* your Bashert?  I could go on, but I won't.

Comment: "bashert" in itself is a vague term. Moreso, who knows why your shidduch said, "no". Trust me, sometimes saying "no" IS, in itself "bashert". It's better than discovering "bad news" after marriage!

Comment: possible duplicate of [40 Days Before Conception](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/40-days-before-conception)

Comment: Many say that "bashert" means "most likely, assuming a standard course of events." Regardless -- if someone says no to you, I think what God wants of you now is to move on.

Comment: Maybe if you pressure them incessantly they'll change their mind to yes...

Comment: There is a story about a person who davenned to meet his bashert. After davenning incessantly, he recieved an answer "You met her but you did not like her accent. A person has free will to refuse his (or her) bashert.

Comment: @sabbahillel This sounds very modern (I understand that the original might be regarding a real mum) but what is the source of this story, is it not a baba mi'sa?

Comment: @hazoriz I think that it is a story of the immigrants in the 1900's that has been around for qa long time. A similar story was told when people were getting nose jobs.

Comment: @DoubleAA, that's exactly the motivation behind this question. How do we know if G-d wants you to incessantly pressure them to change their mind or if you should just move on?

Comment: @ani I was being sarcastic. Don't bother anyone incessantly. Respect their opinions.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I heard stories where the girl refused and their rabbi convinced them to try again and they are now happily married...

Comment: @AniYodea Perhaps if there is a rabbi who feels very strongly that the couple should be together, he can decide to apply the pressure. When a person who is rejected puts a lot of pressure on the person who rejected him to change her mind, he shows himself to be stubborn and unable to take "no" for an answer.

Comment: @AniYodea And I have heard stories where people are annoying and they end up just having been annoying. It's always possible that sometimes people who break rules end up not causing harm, but is it worth it?

Comment: Note that this idea that one's match is predetermined is not universal. Rambam, for example, forcefully rejects it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to check if it is your bashert/zivug is if you get married then yes if you do not then probably no

My understanding for here is  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/52545/5120 is shidduchim is bargaining/negotiations

I also understand that in bargaining /negotiations sometimes you need to say "**no**", that if the other side will not accept or do something then **no** deal

(specifically now when it seems that shidduch decisions are more emotional ("spiritual" ie "what is your hashkofo?") then practical (if we get married we will be able to survive....), And a lot of people do not keep their word "**No**" might not mean anything)

If the other side first says no, but in a month says yes (as @doubleDD said in comment above) and then you get married it is bashert it is the correct zivug (unless you prayed to marry this specific person then it is possible that your prayers will be answered even if it is not your zivug (but it will last for a long time,(maybe since the other party still needs to marry their zivug) see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8125/5120 "
1.**Sefer Chassidim** - "stealing" someone spouse through prayer will only work for a short while. The marriage may not even be consummated. 2. **Chida (1st interpretation) and Ran** - "stealing" someone spouse through prayer will work for a while, but eventually the spouse will marry the one she was supposed to." See the full answer it is interesting))

Source and anyone you marry is your zivug

From Gemoro

מועד קטן יח, ב

> אמר רב משום רבי ראובן בן אצטרובלי מן התורה ומן הנביאים ומן הכתובים **מה' אישה לאיש**. מהתורה דכתיב (בראשית כד, נ), וַיַּעַן לָבָן וּבְתוּאֵל וַיֹּאמְרוּ מֵה' יָצָא הַדָּבָר. מן הנביאים דכתיב (שופטים יד, ד), וְאָבִיו וְאִמּוֹ לֹא יָדְעוּ כִּי מֵה' הִיא. מן הכתובים (משלי יט, יד), בַּיִת וָהוֹן נַחֲלַת אָבוֹת וּמֵה' אישה מַשְׂכָּלֶת

From midrash

בראשית רבה סח
ג

> ר' אבהו פתח: (משלי יט): בית והון נחלת אבות, ומה' אשה משכלת. רבי פנחס בשם ר' אבהו: מצינו בתורה בנביאים ובכתובים, שאין זיווגו של איש אלא מן הקב"ה. בתורה מנין? (בראשית כד): ויען לבן ובתואל ויאמרו מה' יצא הדבר. בנביאים? (שופטים יד): ואביו ואמו לא ידעו כי מה' הוא. בכתובים? היינו דכתיב (משלי יט: ומה' אשה משכלת, יש שהוא הולך אצל זיווגו, ויש שזיווגו בא אצלו. יצחק זיווגו בא אצלו, וירא והנה גמלים באים. יעקב הלך אצל זיווגו, דכתיב: ויצא יעקב:
>   ד
>   רבי יהודה בר סימון פתח: (תהלים סח) אלהים מושיב יחידים ביתה. מטרונה שאלה את ר' יוסי בר חלפתא, אמרה לו: לכמה ימים ברא הקדוש ברוך הוא את עולמו? אמר לה: לששת ימים, כדכתיב (שמות כ): כי ששת ימים עשה ה' את השמים ואת הארץ. אמרה לו: מה הוא עושה מאותה שעה ועד עכשיו? אמר לה: הקב"ה יושב ומזווג זיווגים, בתו של פלוני לפלוני, אשתו של פלוני לפלוני, ממונו של פלוני, לפלוני. אמרה לו: ודא הוא אומנתיה?! אף אני יכולה לעשות כן! כמה עבדים, כמה שפחות יש לי, לשעה קלה אני יכולה לזווגן. אמר לה: אם קלה היא בעיניך, קשה היא לפני הקדוש ברוך הוא, כקריעת ים סוף. הלך לו ר' יוסי בר חלפתא. מה עשתה? נטלה אלף עבדים ואלף שפחות, והעמידה אותן שורות שורות. אמרה: פלן יסב לפלונית, ופלונית תיסב לפלוני, וזיווגה אותן בלילה אחת. למחר אתון לגבה, דין מוחיה פציעא, דין עינו שמיטא, דין רגליה תבירא. אמרה להון: מה לכון? דא אמרה: לית אנא בעי לדין. ודין אמר: לית אנא בעי לדא. מיד שלחה והביאה את ר' יוסי בר חלפתא אמרה לו: לית אלוה כאלהכון, אמת היא תורתכון, נאה ומשובחת! יפה אמרת! אמר: לא כך אמרתי לך: אם קלה היא בעיניך, קשה היא לפני הקב"ה כקריעת ים סוף. הקדוש ברוך הוא מה עושה להן? מזווגן בעל כרחן, שלא בטובתן, הה"ד (תהלים סח): אלהים מושיב יחידים ביתה, מוציא אסירים בכושרות. מהו בכושרות? בכי ושירות. מאן דבעי, אומר שירה! ומאן דלא בעי, בכי! אמר רבי ברכיה: כלשון הזה השיבה ר' יוסי בר חלפתא, הקב"ה יושב ועושה סולמות, משפיל לזה ומרים לזה, ומוריד לזה ומעלה לזה. הוי אומר (תהלים עה): אלהים שופט, זה ישפיל וזה ירים, יש שהוא הולך אצל זיווגו, ויש שזיווגו בא אצלו. יצחק בא זיווגו אצלו, שנאמר (בראשית כד): ויצא יצחק לשוח בשדה. יעקב הלך אצל זיווגו, שנאמר: ויצא יעקב מבאר שבע:

Maybe also from 3rd brocha of sheva brochois

> ...והתקין לו ... בנין עדי עד...