# What is the approximate date of the demarcation between Ashkenazim and Sephardim?

Tags: history, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, historical-figures, ashkenazi

Based on [this article](http://www.jewishhistory.org/sephardim-and-ashkenazim/) it would seem that the transition from a unified people into two groups, Ashkenazim and Sephardim, began in the 9th century and proceeded over time. I would like to know if there is any demarcation as to when these groups were formally viewed as separate, so for example Rabbinic bans enacted by one group would not apply to the other. By way of analogy there are individuals who are seen as the last of a certain era (Tanaaim, Geonim, Rishonim etc.) these people can be viewed as demarcating between one epoch and another even though there was a transition which may have taken years. Does such a thing exist in terms of the split between Ashkenaz and Sephard?

Comment: What about Yemenites? Moroccans? Yekkes? Iraqis? Provencals? Chabadnikim? What are these two distinct groups of which you speak?

Comment: Communal bans are effective over anyone considered a part of the community. They spread as populations move and cultural centers shift. || A given figure may have great influence and many communities listen to him, while other figures had more limited spheres of influence. || The modern distinction between two main groups is the result of local variation being wiped out over time such as during the upheaval following the first world war, and even more so after the second.

Comment: [cont.] There used to be much more variation between communities in different countries and different countries, e.g. France, Germany, England, Italy, Spain, Portugal, Morocco, Tunisia, Algeria, Egypt, Israel, Syria, and Iran. || The distinct Ashkenazi culture / tradition is first recorded in 10th century Rhineland.

Comment: @DoubleAA I am asking when the classification of "Ashkenaz" and "Sephard" began, that is all.

Comment: @rikitikitembo But you do not provide evidence that such a classification even exists. If you mean as a commons linguistic convention, that seems off topic.

Comment: @mevaqesh I agree with you that this was a process over time, hence my example of a person who is used to demarcate the transition in epochs. I am looking for a similar demarcation for this historical process, should one exist.

Comment: @mevaqesh not as a linguistic convention but as something formally recognized either by halacha, minhag or the like. I assume you would agree that there are differences in minhagim between the two groups, my question then is simply when did they 'become' to groups

Comment: Since the 10th century the number of distinct groups has grown over the centuries, and then shrunk under the uniting influence of Bavli, Mishneh Torah, Tosafist movement, Shulhan Arukh, and resettlement in Israel and America. I suspect that the broad linguistic convention is <700 years old. || As noted, even today there are Teimonim, for example who are definitely neither Ashkenazi nor Sephardi (particularity Baladi Teimonim). || BTW the distinction between Geonim and Rishonim is pretty arbitrary. What are Rav Nissim Gaon, Rabbenu Hananel and R. Shmuel HaNaggid.

Comment: And Rishonim generally argue on Geonim with impunity, so the distinction is more significant to a historian broadly describing history than to e.g. halakha. || Editing in how you know that Jews are halakhically divided into two groups, rather than lumping them together for linguistic convenience, and where you think Teimonim fit into this distinction would improve the question.

Comment: @riki I don't know what that classification is, so it'd be hard to find its origin.

Comment: To some extent, it began with the communities of Israel and Babylonia. Tosefos sometimes reconciles Ashkenazi practice which sometimes had a Yerushalmi basis with the dominant Bavli. Of course, this predates the off topic Yiddish / Ladino linguistics and there's a lot more to it than that.

Comment: similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9153/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2099/759

Comment: Thank you Ploni Almoni. It's a bit more complicated; it's more like Sepharadim are more purely Babylonian in practice, while the migrations that converged in Ashkenaz (including people coming from Italy to the new heart of the Holy Roman Empire, immigrants from Provence and surrounding areas, etc...) were more of a mix of Babylonian and Israeli traditions.

Comment: But in any case, I would guess the cultural divide was really caused by the Crusades, and the lack of communication that ensued between Moslem and Xian countries while the two were at war.

Comment: You've answered your own question: "Ashkenazim and Sephardim, began in the 9th century and proceeded over time.  Do you want a date? May 4, 1066?  It doesn't work like that.  There is no date, it isn't like one day they woke and said: "hey, we're Ashkenazi now, let us stop with the Moroccan spices, and break out the herring!  It's about communities addressing individual needs, that over time began to be a prevalent adoption of customs.  History is about the process, it happens over a period of 400 years.

Comment: Communities become isolated, and customs develop.  To show you - there began different schools of learning - the Spanish schools and French schools and German schools.  These come from different approaches from the students of the Gaonim.  This probably had a profound impact on customs.  We know that the Rosh and the Tur (clear French/Ashkenazi Rishonim) who lived in Spain.  The Rambam traveled from Spain, to Fez, to Egypt to Eretz Yisrael - very different communities and customs.

Answer (score 2):

Edit based on the discussion in the comments:
As the OP mentioned, this demarcation can't be accurately attributed to a specific time, because A. Differentiating between Ashkenazim and Sephardim oversimplifies the differences between communities in Europe, Africa and the middle East, and B. Even if we oversimplify in such a way, it was a process of probably hundreds of years until the split was complete (or as complete as it ever got).

Even so, I tried answering the question in a way that shows that a majority of (what we now call) Ashkenazim paskened differently than a majority of (what we now call) Sephardim and other non- European communities, this showing that the demarcation had already begun to take effect.

One early sign of this demarcation is the Cherem d'Rabbeinu Gershom on marrying two wives. Rabbinic Gershom Maor Hagolah was a Rosh Yeshiva in Germany during the late 10th and early 11th century, and his takkana was accepted by all of European (Ashkenazi) Jewry, but not by most Sefardi or other communities (see, for example, Yabia Omer part 8 Even Ha'ezer 2).

Though it's not fully clear *when* all of the Ashkenazi communities accepted this takana, of note is the fact that (according to Wikipedia https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9D) most of the gedolim of the generation after rabbeinu Gershom were his students, and Rashi wrote about him:

> רבינו גרשום זכר צדיק וקדוש לברכה שמאיר עיני גולה וכולנו מפיו חיין וכל בני גלות אשכנז וכיתים תלמידי תלמידיו הן
>
> Rabbeinu Gershom zecher tzadik vekadosh l'bracha, who lights up the eyes of the exiled and from whose mouth we all live and **all of the exiled of Ashkenaz and kittim (understood to mean Italy) are students of his students**

In addition to Rashi quoting the takana outright in one of his t'shuvos (quoted by the Mordechai Bava Kama siman 210) which indicate that his psaks, and especially his Cherem, were probably well accepted almost immediately (Rashi was only a generation younger than rabbeinu Gershom) among the Ashkenazi communities.

In the comments, a claim was made that maybe some Sephardim also accepted the takana at first, and then later changed their minhag to match other communities. While this could be true, it must have been on a small enough scale that it's rarely mentioned, and not paskened at all, among the Sephardi rishonim, which doesn't affect the claim that at this point in time there was a clear demarcation.

This is the first relatively clear demarcation I could find between Ashkenazi Jews and others (Sephardi, Yemenite etc.), though it may have happened earlier.

Comment: When did this difference in acceptance happen? The way "ashkenazi" and "sefardi" communities now view this ban isn't necessarily how everyone always did.

Comment: @DoubleAA, it must have been pretty early, at least on the Sefardi side not accepting it, because otherwise there would be more difference of opinion/ different minhagim within the Sefardi umbrella of communities, presumably

Comment: @DoubleAA edited my answer to address your comment

Comment: I find the historical analysis of the spread of this enactment severely lacking. Your best argument is just from the fact that Rashi thought to describe a group of people as Ashkenazim. At the time there were groups of European Jews in Germany France Provence Italy Greece Castille Aragon Portugal with their own cultures, so still not much support for the two groups in question Ashkenaz and Sefarad.

Comment: @DoubleAA true, but seeing as (per Wikipedia) most of the gedolim of Europe the generation after rabbeinu Gershom were his own talmidim, and communities tend to follow the psaks of gedolim even when they're not from the same country, it seems safe to say that at least most of Europe adopted rabbeinu Gershoms psak. Especially since, AFAICT, the only (and certainly the biggest) centers of Torah in Europe were in France, Italy, and Germany, all of which followed rabbeinu Gershom

Comment: (Pt. 2). Italy and France followed rabbeinu Gershom as per rashis letter, Germany followed him, seeing as that's where rabbeinu Gershom was Rosh yeshiva and leader. I don't mean to say that all of Europe were the same in their minhagim and halachos at that point (because that was never, and still isn't, true). However, it seems like a point in time where there were already clear lines between European and other Jewry

Comment: Spain is in Europe

Comment: (as for the many Jewish communities you mentioned: Germany, France and Italy kept rabbeinu Gershoms psak; Portugal was long under Islam rule and was probably Sefardi, same as Castille (and Aragon, IIRC); Provence was between Italy and France and probably had the same psaks as them. Greece was the only community mentioned that I concede might have had a different ruling

Comment: @DoubleAA , sorry I should have been clearer. When I used 'European', I was referring to what we now call 'ashkenazi'. I didn't want to use the term Ashkenazi so as not to make it confusing. Guess it didn't work :-)