When did they start using the term ashkenazi?
About what year was the term Ashkenazi first used? Was it first used only for German Jews or also for French Jews?

Ashkemaz Means Germany so Ashkenazi Jews originally referred to German Jews though it became later more widely applied to European Jews. This question is more about Jews rather than Judaism and doesn't fit this website though

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85507/what-is-the-approximate-date-of-the-demarcation-between-ashkenazim-and-sephardim

@Dude I think it's still a fair question -- when, and how, does the halachic literature begin using that term, in its narrower sense -- Germany -- and in its broader sense as we know it today. (How does Rabbi Moshe Isserles describe "his world" vs. Rabbi Karo's world? Today, we'd all call Rashi and Rabbi Isserles "Ashkenazim", though the former lived mostly in France, and the latter AFAIK never set foot in Germany.)

Sorry this one got closed. But in the medieval era, "Ashkenaz" meant Germany. The term later broadened to "non-Mediterranean European Jews."
